# Pair unordered_map STL search for both

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap

I want to create a hashmap that I can search for both part of the key somehow. Say I have a pair and I want this to be the key. I wouldn't like to search for the exact {string, id} but sometime to search for the int and sometime for the string, is it possible to do this?

Comment: You might be looking for [Boost Multiindex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do it. You just have to implement a custom container that implements all these operations efficiently. Sounds like a fun excersize, good luck!

Comment: @Sam where would I start?

Comment: There happens to be a fairly simple way to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper, and write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: [boost::bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) will do the job

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I need 2 searching functions I guess, but they need to be hash functions so how would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean "how would I do that"? Every question, related to C++ that only says "how would I do that", and nothing more, has the same exact answer: write C++ code that implements it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How would I pick such hash functions? How do I know they are good enough?

Comment: That's something you need to figure out by yourself. You need to analyze what kind of data you're going to be hashing, and then analyze each hash function candidate to make sure that it provides a reasonable spread over the hash space. This can be done only by examining the actual data being hashed, and of all the users on stackoverflow.com, there is only one user who has access to the data, and can perform this analysis. That, of course, would be you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible ! However it's not that useful and has a bad design .

The solution is to use a custom compare type which will customize the comparing operation . If you want one behavior from the comparer then you only need a free context compare type which does whatever you want .

But if you want to alter the behavior from outside the map as needed you will use a comparer with a context which outlives the map

```
struct CompareContext
{
   bool id = false;
};

struct Comparer
{
   const CompareContext& ctx;

   using arg_t = std::pair<std::string, int>;

   Comparer(const CompareContext& ctx) : ctx{ ctx } {}

   bool operator()(const arg_t& first, const arg_t& second) const
   {
       if (ctx.id)
       {
           std::less<int> l;
           return l(first.second, second.second);
       }
       else
       {
           std::less<std::string> l;
           return l(first.first, second.first);
       }
   }

};


int main()
{
    CompareContext ctx;
    Comparer comp{ ctx };
    using key_t = Comparer::arg_t;
    using val_t = int;
    using map_t = std::map<key_t, val_t, Comparer>;

    map_t mp{ comp };

}
```

Another example to search using the string or int of key `std::pair<std::string, int>`

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using key_t = std::pair<std::string, int>;
   auto cmp = [](const key_t & first, const key_t& second)
   {
      std::less<int> li;
      if (li(first.second, second.second))
         return true;
      std::less<std::string> ls;
      return ls(first.first, second.first); 
   };

   using map_t = std::map<key_t, int, decltype(cmp)>;

   key_t key1{ "string1", 1 };
   key_t key2{ "string2", 2 };

   map_t mp{ cmp };
   mp.emplace(key1, 1);
   mp.emplace(key2, 2);

   key_t search_1{ "string1", 5 }; // match using string
   key_t search_2{ "string5", 2 }; // match using int
   key_t search_3{ "string3", 3 }; // doesn't exist

   auto it = mp.find(search_1); // search and if not exist returns an iterator to end
   if (it != mp.end())
      std::cout << "Found " << it->second << std::endl;

   auto val = mp[search_2];
   std::cout << "Found " << val << std::endl;

   val = mp[search_3]; // since not found a node will be created with key search_3
   std::cout << "Created a node with int = " << val << std::endl;

}
```

Note that `std::map` doesn't search using equality `lhs == rhs` but compares with less than and greater than since it is sorted and this approach will be faster

On the other hand `std::unordered_map` uses a hasher (usually `std::hash`) to test for equality since it isn't ordered .

Comment: So you re saying now if I say introduce "string1", 1 for the key and I would search for either "string1" or 1 it will return me the element?

Comment: the example I provided allows you to search for either the string or the int not both with the ability to change between while using the map . If you want to search for both and or the result you can implement it the same way and you may not need to use a context . you can even use a lambda as a compare method !

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to add an item in this... and I'm not so sure what you did there, can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Also how can you make it such that it can support "[]" operator? And I don't get how would I search for them.. ?

Comment: see my new example

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the `std::map` give you those kind of options.

Lets say you have `std::map<std::string, int> example = {{"name1", 1},{"name2", id}}; // etc...`

Use `find` to search the key (i.e string):

```
if (example.find("name2")!= example.end()) {
   // Success
}
```

Use for to iterate the map and find your value:

```
for(const auto& itr : example){
   if(itr.second == int_value) return true;
}
```

Or use this class I made for you:

```
template<class T, class K, class value_compare = std::equal_to<K>, class key_compare = std::less<T> >
class MyMap : public std::map<T, K>
{
    value_compare vc;
    key_compare kc;

    using my_iterator = typename std::map<T, K, key_compare>::iterator;

public:

    my_iterator find_value(const K val) {
        my_iterator itr = std::map<T, K>::begin();
        my_iterator map_end = std::map<T, K>::end();

        for (; itr != map_end; ++itr)
        {
            if (vc(itr->second, val)) return itr;
        }

        return itr;
    }

};
```

used it the same as `std::map` except now you can invoke `find_value` and get the first iterator which point to the map pair. (if you want list or some other return value change it)

Example:

```
MyMap< std::string, int>  ss_map;

ss_map["aab"] = 1;
ss_map["aba"] = 2;
ss_map["aaa"] = 3;
ss_map["abb"] = 4;
ss_map["baa"] = 5;

auto itr = ss_map.find("abb"); // return iterator<pair<"abb",4>>

auto itr2 = ss_map.find_value(2); // return iterator<pair<"aba",2>>
```